# Crystal report displays ###### in decimal fields

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, decimal

I'm using Crystal report to generate reports to my c# application, But the

decimal fields displays as #####. I'm using VS 2010 professional, .Net 4.5 and

SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio SP5.

How to fix this problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the field isn't wide enough to display all the digits, perhaps make it wider or format it to reduce the number of digit, for example, 2 decimal places?

Comment: Thank you very much i make it wider and it is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Crystal Reports` (and also Microsoft Excel) displays hashes when the content is too large to fit in the container. In this case your decimal number likely has too many digits to fit. There are two simlpe solutions:

1. Make your container wider
2. Format the number to reduce the number of digits, usually this means picking a number of decimal places to show. So for example `1.23456789` will show as `1.23`.